# 1 app (on a fileserver) running differently on 2 pcs

Tags: c#, fileserver

I've developed a C# application that simply reads from a table in a database "FinishedOrders" and puts the results into a list view.

And basically the problem is:

When i run the application on my laptop (the computer used to develop it) off of the file server it works properly and fills the list with the values from the Finished Orders table

When I run the exact same application from the exact same path on my bosses computer it pops up an empty list view as if it caught an exception or something.

**Things I've considered:**

- Wrapping the entire loading statement in a try catch block and having it spit out the error message in a message box doesn't show an error on either computer.
- I'm using a list of stack panels, and the first item in each stack panel is an Image control, I'm setting the image.source like this: `Type.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Control;component/images/42EF.png", UriKind.Relative));` Now I'm not entirely sure if this is causing the problem but if it couldn't load the uri wouldn't it throw an error message within a try catch block instead of just not showing ?
- I've copy pasted the entire solution instead of just the application onto the fileserver and tried running it from the debug folder (on both computers) -> same problem
- I've tried changing my connection strings to both a mapped drive "T:...." and "\Fileserver..." both work on my computer. The database is on the fileserver as well.
- Both computers are using windows 7 (although i think my boss has premium edition, I have ultimate)
- Both computers have access installed and have other tested and working C# applications using ole.db in pretty much the exact same context.

this is my code: http://pastebin.com/hm0BByDf

Comment: You're wrapping it in a `try...catch` -- are you seeing any exceptions?

Comment: Nothing =/    . . . . .

Comment: Not wanting to be unkind but when you fix the bug you might also want to refactor your code... One key example is you do `switch (iRead["PoolType"].ToString())` and then on the case seem to just set the name, so `case "42EF":` then does `BitmapImage(new Uri("/Control;component/images/42EF.png"`. Why not just do away with switch and use `string.format`? But generally it could do with a bit of a code review.

Comment: Because sometimes there's other types that pop up that i don't have images for, with the switch i can make use of the "Default" statement

Comment: Use Caspol in both your pc and your boss' one to check permissions and policies

Comment: On another note does the `/Control...42EF.png` etc path exist on both machines? Also, are they both the same date format (i.e. UK or US) as you are parsing a date using mid (not great idea). Again, not wanting a downer but your queries are open to injection too and you should use parameters.

Comment: The exact same numbers appear in the text box at the bottom on both computers "29052013" so mid function is fine, and I'm somewhat unworried about injection on my application used by 1 person, @ManueldelCastillo That's a very good point, But I have other applications writing to the same database (different table) from his computer working already

Comment: You could try some quick and dirty debug to get you going: Add a `MessageBox` as the first instruction after the `while (iRead.Read()) {` (so before `StackPanel s = new StackPanel();` so you can check that it is returning a record(s). You then know it is at least hitting that point and suggests something wrong building up list. If you don't see that suggests database or record issue.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea

Comment: @JustinKirk - Did that shed any light on the issue?

Comment: I opened the connection successfully, i opened the reader successfully, the messagebox after the imagesource stuff didn't pop up (but didn't hit the catch block for whatever reason) anyway, I've changed the source to image files directly in the folder like `Type.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("42EF.png", UriKind.Relative));` And i'm doing other stuff until my boss leaves his computer so i can test, the only downfall of this will be the folder will be cluttered. But he's probably just going to use the shortcut anyway

Comment: Okay, great. Sounds like you are making progress and keep us updated!

Comment: If this code will be shared, I'd rethink your variable names...

Comment: Even after changing it to the image names without any other folder and placing all the images into the local folder it still works on mine and doesn't work on his -_- , And there's no way he'll open the c# file in notepad and read through the variable names. If i get it to work i'll probably remove the solution (since he doesn't have visual studio) anyway, and even if he does he has a sense of humor, hopefully he'll laugh ^_^

Comment: If my boss has office (and access) 2003 installed on his computer, maybe 2003 doesn't have the mid function ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error and i'm quite annoyed with it really.

When i open the access database (on the fileserver) with my computer, the dates are all in the format **ddmmyyyy** when i open the exact same database from my bosses computer in access 2003 it shows the dates in the format of **mmddyyyy** The list shows blank on his computer because i'm querying the date in the wrong format

He had his region set to English(United States) which by default puts month first
I have mine set to English(Canada)